# Grid area messing up text. How do I get text to not be on top of each other? And how do I align it vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what is currently looks like:
[image]

Obviously I don't want the text on top of each other. This is what I want it to look like (apologies for the lackluster drawing):
[image]

I want the text to apply to all of them (that is what the lines are for) and to look like this:

> Text 1
>
> Text 2
>
> Text 3

Instead of, you know, the jumbled mess I have now.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Explore The Stephen King Database</h1>
    <div id="searchWrapper">
        <input
            type="text"
            name="searchBar"
            id="searchBar"
            placeholder="What would you like to search for?"
        />
    </div>
    <ul id="booksList"></ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}

#booksList {
    padding-inline-start: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

#booksList li {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.character {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #111111;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        'name image'
        'house image';
    text-align: left;
}

.character > h2 {
    grid-area: name;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.character > p {
    grid-area: house;
    margin-top: -18px;
}

.character > img {
    max-height: 150px;
    grid-area: image;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
const booksList = document.getElementById('booksList');
let skBooks = [];

const loadLayout = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('data.json');
        skBooks = await res.json();
        displayCharacters(skBooks);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayCharacters = (books) => {
    const htmlString = books
        .map((books) => {
            return `
            <li class="character">
                <h2>${books.name}</h2>
                <p>${books.pubDate}</p>
                <p>${books.pageCount}</p>
                <p>${books.publisher}</p>
                <img src="${books.image}"></img>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    booksList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadLayout();
```

The solution I tried earlier was removing the `grid-area: house;` from the `.character > p` selector, and it does separate the text, but it unalign's it to where it looks like this:
[image]

And, of course, like I drew I want it to be aligned vertically with a little bit of space in between.

Anyways, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi I think the bulk of the HTML is created by the JS.

Comment: You are putting all 3 p elements in the same cell so they occupy the same space.

Comment: Rightly pointed out by @AHaworth. I made a codepen for your reference. https://codepen.io/sherloke/pen/RwZxzgg

Comment: Got it to work by adding that div. Thank you!!